# Import database schema

Tags: mysql, import, schema

I am having a mysqldump file which contains schema as well as data dump.

I need to import only database schema from my sqldump. I tried with following command:

```
mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD < filename.sql
```

but of no help. it imports both schema as well as data.

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you expect mysql to selectively ignore SQL code in `filename.sql`?

Comment: first make sure you have backed up only the schema , the command for importing will be same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the easiest solution is to just open the dump in a regular text editor and copy the `CREATE TABLE ...` statements into another file. I would not even care about doing anything else.

If that's not an option for whatever the reason, you can simply create a new dump and this time separate structure and data in two files.

If that's not an option either, you can load the dump into a local MySQL server create the new dump from there, or use a GUI tool like HeidiSQL to transfer the structure right into the destination server.

Answer (score 6):

Just in case you don't want to dump everything again and you just need it for some quick tests you could also cheat **very** dirty by using

```
grep -ve '^INSERT' dump.sql > dump-no-data.sql
```

Don't use this for production environments though.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can't as if it's in the dump, it will be inserted again.

What you can do is dump a database without the data in the first place using the `-no-data` option:

`mysqldump -u username -p -h localhost –no-data database_name > dump.sql`

Answer (score 1):

if you want try this:

```
mysql -u USER -pPASSWORD database < database_schema.sql
```