# How to get all table information from a huge mySQL dump?

Tags: mysql, import

I'm newbie to SQL, and I just want to understand what huge dump file contains (tables, variables, etc) without importing it. I found only [those answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355996/import-database-schema) which suggests to grep CREATE TABLE statements or INSERT's. Is there any convenient automated way to extract correct database structure, all variables, etc from dump file, i.e. the same thing that one would have doing `mysqldump --no-data`?

As far, as I understand, I need to process dump file in sections "Table structure for table", omitting INSERT statements, so how can I do it?

Comment: Excluding the INSERTs with `grep -v` is the way to go, like one of the answers suggested.

Comment: @fancyPants Thanks, man! You saved me so much effort!